# How to modify a file according to user input in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I've a file with the below contents

```
A     B     C
1     2     3
4     5     6
7     8     9
```

Lets say the user input 1
Then the file should change to

```
A     B     C
X     2     3
4     5     6
7     8     9
```

Or if the user input 1,2 Then the file should change to

```
A     B     C
X     X     3
4     5     6
7     8     9
```

I'm new to bash so any help is appreciated

Comment: It is doable.  A bit of if-then-else logic and echo statements.  What have you tried?  SO is not a code writting service, but we will helpyou if you get stuck.

Comment: What is required if there is also a line `10    11    12` and the user enters `1` ?  Should that line be `X0    XX    X2`, or should it be unchanged?

Comment: I got the answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we supposse that the data file names matrix.txt and we make a script to edit the content of the data file.

matrix.txt:

```
A     B     C
1     2     3
4     5     6
7     8     9
```

And we make this script:

matrix_script.sh:

```
read -p "Input: " input
sed "s/$input/X/g" matrix | tee matrix
```

this changes the number that you write by a 'X'.

The read command reads from keyboard until you press 'Enter'. The '-p' option writes a message before you can write. The 'input' variable is where the 'read' command stores the value that you wrote.

The 'sed' command is for replace the a character for other. We said to sed that we want to replace the value of the 'input' variable for the 'X' character in the 'matrix' file. This copy the content of the matrix file with the changes but no write the changes on the input file. To fix this, we duplicate the output (with the 'tee' command) of the sed command, and one of these outputs will write on the 'matrix' file.

Try it and talk to us if this script works as you want.

Bye

Comment: `sed x | tee x` is not reliable -- both `sed` and `tee` are started at the same time, so you're relying on luck in terms of whether `sed` reads from the file or `tee` deletes its old contents first.

Comment: I use this a lot of times and i never have been this problem. But just in case I will consider it for other scripts.

Comment: See [Linux: Write into same file with awk and tee --
 very odd behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149972/linux-write-into-same-file-with-awk-and-tee-very-odd-behaviour) for one example (albeit it's a different formulation where it's the shell, and not `tee`, opening the output file, so the output end is more likely to win than the input one in that scenario).

Comment: [Updating a file using tee randomly fails in linux bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38852767/updating-a-file-using-tee-randomly-fails-in-linux-bash-script) is closer to the version that you suggest here.

Comment: ...anyhow, while `sed -i` isn't portable, when it *is* available it does the proper write-to-a-temporary-file-and-atomically-rename approach, making it more reliable.

Comment: This works for me but for the last part i changed from tee to the below                         sedtest.txt > sedtest2.txt mv –f sedtest2.txt sedtest.txt

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v cols="$cols" 'NR==2{n=split(cols,f,","); 
                             for(i=1;i<=n;i++) sub($i,"X")}1' file
```

assumes your user input is assigned to the bash variable `cols`.  Pass the values to `awk` under the same name.  Find the values and substitute one at a time only for the second row; print all rows.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I used the sed example from above as I understand sed better